# Loop While se ejectua sólo una vez?

Tags: java, while

qué tal?

Estoy tratando de hacer funcionar este while loop para calcular el mayor divisor de un número, pero el loop solo se ejecuta una vez en vez de respetar la condición de correr hasta que el divisor sea mayor que el número a dividir.

Alguien me puede orientar? Lo probé con un for loop y obtengo el mismo resultado. Gracias.

*pd: el metodo podría no estar bien, pero de todas maneras me interesa hacer andar el loop primero.*

```
int numero = 12;
int mayorDivisor = 0;
int calculation = 0;    
int divider = 1;

        while(divider <= numero){

            calculation = numero %= divider;
            System.out.println("remainder is " + calculation);
            if (calculation == 0){ 
            divisorA = divider;
            System.out.println("divisorA is now " + divisorA);
            }
            divider++;
            System.out.println("divider is now " + divider);

        }
```

Comment: ¿Cúal es el valor de numero?

Comment: En el caso de prueba, 12.

Comment: Cambia **calculation = numero %= divider;**  por ***calculation = numero % divider;***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el cálculo del residuo que haces en la primera instrucción, estás usando el operador `%` junto a `=`. Eso le asigna otro valor a `numero`, muy seguramente le asigna el valor del cálculo del residuo (que comenzando por 1 en `divider`, debería ser cero). Luego aumentas `divider++` y ya la condición no se cumple.

Tu código debería andar así (sólo cambio la línea en el cálculo del residuo):

```
while(divider <= numero){

        calculation = numero % divider;
        System.out.println("remainder is " + calculation);
        if (calculation == 0){ 
           divisorA = divider;
           System.out.println("divisorA is now " + divisorA);
        }
        divider++;
        System.out.println("divider is now " + divider);

}
```

Para este tipo de dudas, procura hacerle seguimiento (debug) al código. En cualquier IDE es fácil poner interrupciones para poder pausar la ejecución y ver qué valor tienen tus vaiables. Como mínimo, puedes hacer muchos `system.out.println("variable: " + tu_variable)` (que es una mala práctica pero es mejor que nada).

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, me interesó eso de las interrupciones, ya que siempre uso `system.out.println` para hacer el seguimiento. Tenes algún link en español?

Comment: @JuanRom Pues a mí estas guías siempre me han parecido fáciles de entender: [Sobre Eclipse](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html). O [sobre IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html).

Comment: no está en español y además uso netbeans, pero gracias igualmente, por lo menos ya sé cómo lo tengo que buscar

Comment: @JuanRom no vi que la pedías en español, lo lamento. A eso, súmale que no es trivial encontrar documentación en español para algunas cosas (podríamos crearla, jeje). Y la [que hay](https://techlandia.com/depurar-codigo-java-netbeans-como_248985/) no suele ser tan cool. Dale una probada al traductor de Chrome, que alguna idea da de lo que dice. :)

Comment: ah buena idea, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En la primera línea de tu "while" usas el operador %= (módulo y asignación) que probablemente ésta cambiando el valor de "divider" a uno que no es el que quieres.

> '%=' : op1 %= op2 puede cambiarse por op1 = op1 % op2